# Resize the width of the div in mobile phone

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. One is 15%, and the other is 76%. I want to hide the 16% div on mobile phones. That is being achieved using this.

```
class="navbar hidden-xs"
```

And the code is as follows

```
#right {
  top: -1px;
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  width: 15%;
}
```

However, when I change the screen size, the box is getting hidden but the space remains there. I want to make the width of the content to 100% in mobile-only. How can I achieve this? My code for the content is as follows:

```
#content {
      float: right;
      width: 76%;
}
```

Comment: You have to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Something like this: @media (max-width: 460px) { #content{width:100%;float:none} }

Comment: can you show me an example with above problem i am a backend guy dont have much exp in frontend

Comment: Those class names look familiar, are you using a UI framework like bootstrap already? If so the work is already done for you with the media queries and utility classes

Comment: Yeah i am using bootstrap @ChrisW.

Comment: Which version? We'll make this extra easy on ya.

Comment: /*!
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

Comment: Let bootstrap [do the work](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/css/#responsive-utilities) then dude. The grid, the utilities classes, all of that exists to make this a non-issue.

Comment: can you show me how to do this in boots trap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #right {
    display: none;
  }
  #content {
    width: 100%;
    float: none
  }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to declare #right and #content two times?

Comment: Once without the media query, and after that you can write as many media queries as you want, for different breakpoints.